# tomcat disable access to application from root application

Tags: java, tomcat, cpanel

I have a domain(say 'maindomain.com') pointing to root application of tomcat, and another domain(say 'addondomain.net') pointing to `addondomain` application in tomcat. 
Both are functioning well.Now I want users to access the addondomain application only from addondomain.net. But it is also accesible from `maindomain.com/addondomain` url. 
How can I prevent this?

Comment: Your ? was tagged with cpanel; are you specifically looking for a way to do this from there?

Comment: You can edit the `web.xml` file of the `ROOT` application and redirect or restrict access to `/addondomain`